# powershell parameter of time period, i.e. Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server Mailbox01 -Start "03/13/2015 09:00:00" -End "03/15/2015 17:00:00"

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm using powershell to retrieve some info from exchange. i.e.

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server Mailbox01 -Start "03/13/2015 09:00:00" -End "03/15/2015 17:00:00"
```

My question is: this cmdlet retrieves messages whose timestamp is:

```
**"03/15/2015 17:00:00" > dt >= "03/13/2015 09:00:00"**
```

or

```
**"03/15/2015 17:00:00" >= dt >= "03/13/2015 09:00:00"**
```

or else?

In the doc, it does not mention anything about this. Maybe it does not matter much, but I just want to know the exact answer. Anyone knows this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the doc, it does not mention anything about this.

The documentation is actually pretty clear on this.

From the **Parameters** section of the help page for the [`Get-MessageTrackingLog` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997573(v=exchg.141).aspx) for Exchange 2010 (holds true in subsequent versions as well):

> The *End* parameter specifies the end date and time to return message tracking log entries. Entries are returned up to, **but not including**, the specified date and time.

Comment: cool. I can not believe I missed that! it is **"03/15/2015 17:00:00" > dt >= "03/13/2015 09:00:00"** in case someone else needs it. thanks again.